# Encoding with ZipFile Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to generate an `.xml` file using the library `ZipFile` in `python 3.9`.
The content i'm trying to add is the following : `"Invoice n°123456789"`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from zipfile import ZipFile

def gen_zip():

  # Init xml element
  root = ET.Element("MyXml")
  # Fill SubElement
  batch = ET.SubElement(
      root,
      "Batch",
      Id="1",
      DateTime=datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"),
      Value = "Invoice n°123456789"
  )

  zf = ZipFile("myzip.zip", "w")
  # Write xml to zip
  zf.writestr("file.xml", ET.tostring(root))
  zf.close()

  return None
```

The problem i have is that the content of my file `file.xml` in `myzip.zip` is the following :

```
<MyXml>
  <Batch Id="1" DateTime="20221207093739" Value="Invoice n&#176;123456789"/>
</MyXml>
```

I don't know why the `°` symbol becomes `&#176;`. As per the doc the `writestr` function does `utf-8` encoding and not `unicode`.  (https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)

I'd like the content of my `.xml` to be `Invoice n°123456789` i/o `Invoice n&#176;123456789`

Comment: This has nothing to do with `ZipFile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the correct encoding as a parameter when you call `tostring`.

```
zf.writestr("file.xml", ET.tostring(root, encoding='unicode'))
```